# Kafka consumer : offset lag between consumer and poducer

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am writing a Kafka consumer application where I have one consumer for each partition. The code is shown below

```
while (true) {  
  ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(100);   
        for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {     
            System.out.printf("topic = %s, partition = %s, offset = %d, customer = %s, country = %s\n",        
            record.topic(), record.partition(), record.offset(), record.key(), record.value());   
 }    
  consumer.commitAsync(new OffsetCommitCallback() {       
        public void onComplete(Map<TopicPartition, OffsetAndMetadata> offsets, Exception e) {  
           if (e != null)              
              log.error("Commit failed for offsets {}", offsets, e); }}); 
}
```

Is there a way to programmatically access and print the consumer *lag offset*, or otherwise said **the difference in positions between the offset of the last record read by the consumer and the offset of the last record written into that consumer partition by a certain producer.**

What statements should I add to the above to get the **lag offset value**, knowing that my final goal is to send this value to prometheus for monitoring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is to have the data in prometheus, you should use the `records-lag` metrics emitted by Consumers.

In the last table in the [Consumer Fetch Metrics section](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumer_fetch_monitoring) in the docs, you can see that Consumers emit lag (and lead) per topic-partition.

By default, metrics are emitted via JMX, so you could use [Prometheus' JMX exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/jmx_exporter) to do the job for example.

Answer (score 1):

There are various options that you can do to monitor your consumer lags.

#### Using KafkaConsumer's endOffsets API

According to the JavaDocs on the [KafkaConsumer](https://kafka.apache.org/22/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#endOffsets-java.util.Collection-) you can make use of `endOffsets` method to "Get the end offsets for the given partitions."

#### Using JMX Metrics

You could make use of Kafka's monitoring capabilities using JMX metrics. In the Documentation on [Monitoring Kafka](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#monitoring) it is explained how to get the "Number of messages the consumer lags behind the producer by. Published by the consumer, not broker."